# How to upload file in multipart/formdata using Delphi TIdHTTP.Post rest API

Tags: api, delphi, file-upload, indy10

In the Netherlands (in future UK too), we have a govermental API service for calculating depositions (AERIUS). This is based on an HTTP REST protocol using the JSON format. I'm using the Delphi Indy 10 version of `TIdHTTP`, which until now was working excellent for this service. However, the way files need to be send to the server has been changed, and from now on `multipart/form-data` is required.

The error I get is:

> http/1.1 415 (unsupported media type)

I understand from many similar problems that `Accept` and `ContentType` must be set. However as @RemyLebeau said, the last regarding the file-sending part is done in the `TIdMultPartFormDataStream`.

```
var
  LParamToSend: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;   
const
  cFileName = 'c:\...\filename.gml';
begin
   LParamToSend := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;

   // example on connect.aerius.nl/api "POST receptorSets", where the upload of this file is fine:
   // curl -X POST "https://connect.aerius.nl/api/v7/receptorSets" -H  "accept: application/json" 
   //      -H "api-key: f6...c" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
   //      -F "receptorSet={"name": ... see below ...}" -F "filePart=@cFileName"

   FHttp.HandleRedirects := True;   
   FHttp.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
   FHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('api-key', edtAPIcode.Text);
   LParamToSend.AddFormField('receptorSet',
              '{"name":"example","description":"testing","expectRcpHeight":false}');
   LParamToSend.AddFile('filePart', cFileName);
   try
      edtMemo.Text := FHttp.Post('https://connect.aerius.nl/api/v7/receptorSets', LParamToSend);
   except
      on E: Exception do
         edtMemo.Text := edtMemo.Text + e.Message;
   end;
   LParamToSend.Free;
end;
```

Finally, I found the solution myself. Since this is my first question, I will share the answer, so it might be helpful for others as well. `ContentType` AND `ContentTransfer` need to be set. Suggestions are wellcome anyway.

```
with LParamToSend.AddFormField('receptorSet',
   '{"name":"example","description":"testing","expectRcpHeight":false}') do begin
   ContentType := '';
   ContentTransfer := '';
end;
LParamToSend.AddFile('filePart', cFileName).ContentTransfer := '';
```

Comment: "*I found the solution myself... I will share the answer*" - the solution should be posted as an actual answer, not as an edit to the question. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: FYI, `AContentType` is an optional parameter of `AddFormField()`. Since you are not passing a value for it, the `TIdFormDataField.ContentType` property will be set to `'text/plain'` by default. And then setting the `TIdFormDataField.ContentType` property afterwards to `''` will set it to `'application/octet-stream'` instead. You can't actually clear the `TIdFormDataField.ContentType` in the current version of Indy.  And yes, I'm aware that this does not jive with the latest flavor of `multipart/form-data` used by HTML5. A future version of Indy will address that.